# Prove that division is possible in the set of real numbers using field axioms

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is this proof correct?
I need to prove that division is possible in the set of real numbers. Given $a$ and $b$ with $a\ne0$ There is exactly one x such that $ax=b$. This x is given by the quotient  $\frac{b}{a}$. In particular $\frac{1}{a}$ is also written as $a^{-1}$ and is called the inverse of $a$.

So this the way I approached the proof using the axioms.
$ax=b$, since I'm working with a field there exists an $a^{-1}$ $a\ne0$ that I can multiply by both sides to get the desired result. $ax(a^{-1})=b(a^{-1})$ and therefore $x=\frac{b}{a}$ when $a\ne0$.

Comment: Depends. If you already know that the real numbers form a field, then this is ok. This question may also come up in the context of **proving** that the real numbers form a field, e.g. when showing that the equivalence classes of Cauchy sequences of rational numbers, with the freshly defined arithmetic operations, form a field.. In such a context you need to prove that $a^{-1}$ exists.

Comment: I think my current knowledge of math does not allow me to prove that the real numbers are a field explicitly so I think it is a fair thing to assume that I already know that the real numbers are a filed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, if $ax= b$, and $a \neq 0$ then there exists some $a'$ with $aa' =1$ by one of the field axioms; we then define $\frac{b}{a}:= a'b$ and then

$$a(a'b) = (aa')b = 1b = b$$ using associativity of multiplication in the first equation and that $1$ is a unit element in the last one.

If $c$ is such that $ac = b$ then $a'(ac) = a'b$ and we get $c =a'b = \frac{b}{a}$ so we have unicity. All this works in any group (and all non-zero field elements form  a group under multiplication).

Answer (score 1):

You probably *shouldn't * prove this for the reals specifically, but should prove it for fields, in general.  Then if you ever are able to state that the reals are a field, it is true because it is true for all fiwlds.

Proposition :  if $F $ is a field and $a\in F;a \ne 0$ and $b\in F $ then there is a unique $x\in F $ so that $ax=b $.  Specifically $x=a^{-1}b $ is always a solution and is always the only solution.

Proof:

(Pretty much what you said).  $a\ne 0$ so by multiplicative identity axiom $a^{-1} $ exists.  By  binarary operation axioms $*$ is a binary operation so $x=a^{-1}b\in F $ exists and is well defined.

$ax=a*(a^{-1}b) $

$=(a*a^{-1})*b $ (associtivity axiom)

$=1*b $ (definition of inverse)

$=b $ (definition of multiplicative identity)

We can prove $x $ is unique as if

$ax=ay=b $ then

$a^{-1}ax=a^{-1}ay=a^{-1}b $

$x=y=a^{-1}b $.

===

That is.... if we are able to state that $\mathbb R $ is a field.

Sometime in your life, it won't be today, but sometime, you will be asked to define what the reals actually *are* and prove/demonstrate/define that they *are* a field.

This isn't *hard*, per se, but it is abstract and pretty obtuse... and *very* tedious.  All I can say is better Deidekin than us.

But the idea is the rationals are an ordered field and they more or less force themselves into existence by induction.  (1 and zero exist.  For all $n $ that exist $n+1$ exist and if $1 >0$ or $1 <0$ then $n+1 > $ or $<$ but in either case is not equal to $n $ or any previously defined.  For any $n $, $-n $ must exist.  And if $n\ne 0$ then $\frac 1n $ exists and for any $m $ then $m/n $ exists and... hey, hey, it's the rationals!)

But the rationals don't have the least upper bound property (it has "holes").  So it becomes a matter of asking: does there exist a field F, that is totally ordered as $\mathbb Q $ is, and that $\mathbb Q\subset F $, and F has the least upper bound property?

The answer is, yes, and the construction and proof of the existence of such a field is an abstract proof (better Deidekin than us).

We then simply call that field $\mathbb R $.  And because it is a field, we can declare division works.

Comment: This is why I find mathematics so fascinating one 'simple' operation such as division has such a beautiful complexity beneath it.